display panel for an SBC?
I'm looking for a display panel for a radxa zero 2 pro, which is a small single board computer with a 39-pin MIPI DSI display connection. Here's a link to the board
https://radxa.com/products/zeros/zero2pro/
Radxa actually sells display panels which are meant to work with their boards, but the largest is 10" (link below). I'm looking for something in the 12-14" range. Any ideas?
https://radxa.com/products/accessories/display-10fhd/#techspec
